# backbone.js events are not bound after model change?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

Here's the code in the view initialize:

```
  var self = this
  this.model.bind('change', function () {
    self.render();
  });
```

I have a bunch of events defined:

```
events: {
  "click #blah": "blah",
},
```

But after changing the model and re-rendering the view the events are no longer bound?

I can bind them by putting a `this.delegateEvents()` in the render, but I don't think that's doing it correctly.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the el property in your view? The events are delegated to this el.

Comment: no. The el is just the automatically created div. the el is recreated every time the render happens, i thought that it was supposed to auto rebind after each render. Is that incorrect?